# How do I resolve Webpack/Angular moduleId error?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webpack, asp.net-core

I built an app that borrows heavily from Dan Wahlin’s [Angular-Jumpstart](https://github.com/DanWahlin/Angular-JumpStart) app, It works when I run it using his ‘npm start’, which looks like this:

```
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"node server.js\"
```

I then used Visaul Studio 2017 to build the ‘*ASP.NET Core + Angular 2 template for Visual Studio*’ app referenced by Scott Sanderson in his [blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/) by the same name. This ASP.NET Core/Angular 2 sample app of his uses Webpack, Server-side rendering, and HMR. It too works fine.

However, I want to add some of the code I created for the Dan Wahlin app into the Scott Sanderson app, and I am running into a **moduleId**-related error. The following is an example of the error message I receive:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: moduleId
>   should be a string in "FilterTextboxComponent". ...If you're using Webpack
>   you should inline the template and the styles...

To resolve this I have tried:

- Removing the moduleId variable from the component(s) in question
- Setting the moduleId varaible in this manner:

  ```
  moduleId: module.id + ''
  ```

I have looked here and elsewhere and have not been able to determine what I need to do to resolve this. Is it a Webpack bug? Am I overlooking something I need to do?

I am happy to provide more information if you think that would help you help me!

Comment: please add the code for the module thats throwing error.

Comment: import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { FilterTextboxModule } from './filter-textbox/filter-textbox.module';
import { PaginationModule } from './pagination/pagination.module';

import { CapitalizePipe } from './pipes/capitalize.pipe';
import { TrimPipe } from './pipes/trim.pipe';
import { SortByDirective } from './directives/sortby.directive';

Comment: @NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, FilterTextboxModule, PaginationModule ],
  exports: [ CommonModule, FormsModule, CapitalizePipe, TrimPipe, SortByDirective,
             FilterTextboxModule, PaginationModule ],
  declarations: [ CapitalizePipe, TrimPipe, SortByDirective ]
})
export class SharedModule { }

Comment: alphapilgrim,I could not fit thew entire code in one comment, so it is broken into the tow comments above. Pardon me if there is a better way to add the code - I didn't know how to do so!

Comment: you can edit your question with code, with code formatting. instead of adding it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was happening...

I would edit the @Component metadata by removing the reference to moduleId in my .ts file and save it, but for some reason Webpack was not transpiling the .ts file into a new .js file. It was just bundling and serving the old .js file.

As to why? ...I think that Webpack uses the .js files when they are present, but will generate its own when they do not exist.